# Stored procedures in jooq with dynamic names

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, jooq

I want to call stored procedures from PostgreSQL in JOOQ by name dynamically:

```
final Field function = function("report_" + name, Object.class, (Field[])params.toArray(new Field[params.size()]));

dsl().select(function).fetchArrays();
```

For example it generates:

```
select report_total_requests('83.84.85.3184');
```

Which returns:

```
 report_total_requests 
-----------------------
 (3683,2111,0)
 (29303,10644,1)
```

And in java it is array of "(3683,2111,0)" objects.

I want to generate:

```
select * from report_total_requests('83.84.85.3184')
```

To produce:

```
total | users | priority 
------+-------+----------
 3683 |  2111 |        0
29303 | 10644 |        1
```

That is in java array of arrays of objects

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use the code generator for this? Because of the generated function name?

Comment: Yes, report functions comes from client, but without prefix to avoid execution any function

Comment: I see, then you *definitely* want to wrap that name into an `org.jooq.Name` object for SQL injection prevention as I've shown in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way forward is to use [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) as follows:

```
Name name = DSL.name("report_" + name);
QueryPart arguments = DSL.list(params);
dsl().select().from("{0}({1})", name, arguments).fetch();
```

Note, I've wrapped the function name in a [`DSL.name()`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names/) object, to prevent SQL injection.